# Let's be hard on [software] and soft on [hardware]

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag [software](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software).

If there's a common theme, it escapes me. I see questions about… well, anything related to software, including using software to protect assets, defeating software countermeasures, using software as part of attacks, protecting software as an asset, etc. That covers almost all the questions on the site, really.

Is there anything to salvage here, or should we just burninate the tag?

The same question goes for [hardware](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware), but I can see it being justified — hardware-based security measures (and corresponding attacks) are a reasonably well-defined subcategory of the site.

Answer (score 7):

Is there a subset of security questions that would benefit from the software tag? If not, I agree with you that we should nuke it. I'll get a full look through, but right now I think you are right.

Hardware works well as a tag, I think.

Comment: "Software" would be a worthwhile tag if there was a non-anecdotic proportion of questions that are not about computers; but there is not. Despite the site having been renamed _information_ security, it still is mostly about _IT_ security. And chimpanzees.

Comment: And bears, obviously...

Answer (score 6):

I agree with removing the [software](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) tag (in almost all cases, this is implied), but I think the [hardware](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) tag should remain, as there are a lot of uses for it.